# log4j : Not logging in file log.out

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am using **log4j** for logging in my project. I tried the below code but it prints on console not in file. Could anyone suggest what is missing, I am using log4j for first time

**Code :**

```
public void testCase1() {
  System.out.println("In test method 1 now");
  Logger log = Logger.getLogger(DisplayCtrlTestCases.class.getName());
  log.debug("Hello this is a debug message");
  log.info("Hello this is an info message");
}
```

**log4j.properties:**

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
#log = /usr/home/log4j
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log}/log.out

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
```

O/P is like :

```
run: 


  [java] log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (ServPackage.Display).[TestNG] Running: 

   [java] log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly. 
   [java] 
   [java] log4j:WARN See logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info. /home/admin/A/In/Servlet/testng.xml 
   [java] 
   [java] 
   [java] In test method 1 now
```

Comment: Is the log4j.properties in your classpath? Can you show the consol output?

Comment: is log.out file being created?

Comment: typical warning when log4j.properties is not found in classpath

Comment: no log.out is not getting created

Comment: as @Jens suggested "Is the log4j.properties in your classpath?"

Comment: @PinkGiraffe The message you posted as Output Shows you thet the log4j.properties is not found.

Comment: ya i have not added in classpath,  but could you tell how to add in classpath ..... sorry for very basic question ..i am just a begineer

Comment: @PinkGiraffe how do you run your program?

Comment: JAVA HOME is added in classpath ...ok i got it tx :)

Comment: @PinkGiraffe do you run it in an IDE or from comandline?

Comment: i am running from cmd ...i think i need to add the cp in build.xml then it will be included

Comment: @Jens .....i have included the lib folder which contains the log4j.jar as well .....then its included already

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
log4j.rootCategory=ERROR, main-appender
log4j.logger.com.lineseiki=DEBUG, console-appender

log4j.appender.main-appender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.main-appender.File=yourProgram.log
log4j.appender.main-appender.Append=true
log4j.appender.main-appender.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.main-appender.MaxBackupIndex=100
log4j.appender.main-appender.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.main-appender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.main-appender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] [%t] [%p] [%c] %m %n

log4j.appender.console-appender=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console-appender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console-appender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%-5p %d] %-20c{1}: %m %n
```

Comment: no, its not working, log4j.properties i included in lib folder which is included in classpath .... by changing the contenets as thsi didint made any change